# Delete a record from table2 after fetched into table1 in sas

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sas

I have two tables:

Table1:

Key p1  calls

```
1A1 ABC 5
2A2 DEF 4
3A3 GHI 3
3A3 JKL 3
4A4 MNO 2
4A4 PQR 2
4A4 STU 2
```

Table2:

```
Key p2  calls
1A1 DEF 5
3A3 JKL 3
4A4 PQR 2
4A4 STU 2
```

My output table should be:

```
key p1  calls p2
1A1 ABC 5     DEF
2A2 DEF 4     .
3A3 GHI 3     JKL
3A3 JKL 3     .
4A4 MNO 2     PQR
4A4 PQR 2     STU
```

i.e., the record in table2 should merge with the first match in table1 and with no other record.
Something like once "3A3 JKL 3" from table2 merged with "3A3 GHI 3" from table1, the record should get deleted from table2.

**Note :** The dot(.) siginifies value missing.

Can someone suggest a way to do this using sql or sas?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I am lost! Your question is very hard to understand. Can you please reformate your question?

Comment: Why have you tagged this with all kinds of sql tags if this is in SAS?  Use [tag:proc-sql] and [tag:sql] and [tag:sas] if it's SAS sql and mysql/(ms) sql server are unrelated.

Comment: Also, when you say 'deleted from' do you mean you want table2 modified?  Or you just mean you want the `JKL` to match the first instance of `3A3` and not the second.

Comment: Joe - What i need is JKL to match the first instance of 3A3 and not the second.

Comment: Mike - What i need is that any row from table2 should match with the first already not matched occurence in table1 and no other row from table1.
Example: 'PQR' from table2 matched with 'MNO' from table1 after this 'STU' from table2 should match with 'PQR' from table1 and not 'MNO' from table1. I hope this helps you understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a SAS way of doing what I think you're asking.  Basically it's a simple merge, tweaked so that P2 is set to missing where KEY in table1 is not the first occurrence of that particular value.  If your data is not sorted then you'll need to do that first.

```
data table1;
input key $ p1 $ calls;
datalines;
1A1 ABC 5
2A2 DEF 4
3A3 GHI 3
3A3 JKL 3
;
run;

data table2;
input key $ p2 $ calls;
datalines;
1A1 DEF 5
3A3 JKL 3
;
run;

data want;
merge table1 (in=a) table2 (in=b);
by key;
if not first.key then call missing(p2);
if a;
run;
```

Comment: Keith - Thanks for your response. What i need is that any row from table2 should match with the first occurence in table1 and no other row from table1. Also, if the row in table1 already has a match in table2 then it is not to be matched again. Hope this explains the question in detail.

Comment: That's what I thought and I believe my code does just that?

Comment: Although I've noticed you've updated your example data where you now have a many-to-many merge which is a bit different to your original posting

Comment: Yes keith. It is a many to many merge forgot to mention that in the example i posted first.
I will run the code you have posted and get back to you.

Comment: Hey keith, i checked out the code you posted. It works like a charm for most of the cases but for one particular key it is having a problem.

Table1:
Key p1  calls
5A5 ABC 2
5A5 DEF 2
5A5 GHI 2
5A5 JKL 2

Table1:
Key p2  calls
5A5 ABC 2
5A5 DEF 2
5A5 GHI 2
5A5 JKL 2

For this case, the records don't exist in the final output.
The match criteria includes that the calls match and p1 and p2 don't.
Can you help?

Comment: A many-to-many merge is a different proposition, particularly given the rules you need to apply in this case.  I think you'd be better off re-posting the question as I'm not sure it can easily be done

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Use `left join` to get the result and `Isnull` to replace **missing** values with **dot(.)**

```
SELECT a.[Key],
       a.p1,
       a.calls,
       Isnull(b.p2, '.') -- For MYSQL change ISNULL to IFNULL()
FROM   table1 a
       LEFT JOIN table2 b
              ON a.calls = b.calls
                 AND a.p1 <> b.p2
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But what i need is not to put '.' in missing places. That is handled automatically. What i need is that any row from data table2 should match with the first occurence in table1 and no other row from table1.